# Azure DevOps VSTest,Site Currently unavailable message and times out despite being up

Tags: selenium, .net-core, selenium-chromedriver, functional-testing, visual-studio-test-runner

Currently using Selenium + ChromeDriver to execute automated functional tests through Azure DevOps VsTest task but whenever the task tries to execute tests pointing to a website in NetCore, it times out very quickly and sometimes (a lot of times) I get the standard error message from the registered screenshot on error of "This site can't be reached".

I tried running this locally and pointing to the same website but this issue doesn't seem to happen at all and I've got no clue on what's going on due to the big inconsistency between the results that the VsTest task provides.

I also tried opening Chrome on the machine that executes the task but it seems to open the URL fine there.

One thing to note is that the website I'm using uses Windows Authentication mechanism and I'm sending my credentials directly through the URL with `https:\\credentialuserexample1:credentialpassexample2@thewebsiteaddress.com` and it seems to open the page without issue there too.

Comment: How about running with self-hosted agent? Does this work?